# Do crystals have healing powers?

Tags: alternative-medicine

Crystal Healing is a common alternative medicine.

For example:

[Crystal Well-Being](http://www.crystalwellbeing.co.uk/introcrystalhealing.php)

> Crystals have a long tradition of being used for crystal healing. Each variety of crystal has a unique internal structure, which causes it to resonate at a certain frequency. It is this resonance that is said to give crystals their healing abilities. Applying this resonance in a coherent way can help to restore stability and balance to the bodies energy systems, stimulating the body's natural healing mechanisms.
>
> Crystal therapy is a gentle non-invasive form of alternative healing that works holistically to harmonize the mind, body, emotions and spirit, helping to increase our feeling of well-being, neutralize negativity, lift depression and to help us to become integrated, whole beings.

Is there any physical evidence that crystals exhibit such properties?

Answer (score 9):

## Short version

There is no evidence that Crystal Healing works, beyond placebo.

## Longer version

Wikipedia introduces [crystal healing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_healing) as a "pseudoscientific alternative medicine technique".

Wikipedia also claims

> There is no peer reviewed scientific evidence that crystal healing has any effect.

While it generally references a book I have never read, *[Crystal Power: The Ultimate Placebo Effect](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN=0879755326/roberttoddcarrolA/)*, it doesn't give a direct reference to support the claim there is no peer-reviewed scientific evidence.

It is hard to prove the absence of scientific evidence, but one standard we use on Skeptics.SE is to find an expert in the area, who has done a search, and rely on that. It isn't perfect (Appeal to Authority), but it is the best we can hope for.

In this case, in 2010, an article was written about oncology in particular:

- [*Mystical stones in oncology: crystal healing power or perfect nonsense?*](http://web.b.ebscohost.com/abstract?direct=true&profile=ehost&scope=site&authtype=crawler&jrnl=09462104&AN=49115546&h=Mwz6o%2fQsYfAtw%2bOaPydHCpgmtailwb7jUb9h5WR76uk45OHxEI3dpevjywZEB%2fcq%2bUzK8AYSqfQXU9RcQnyfEw%3d%3d&crl=c&resultNs=AdminWebAuth&resultLocal=ErrCrlNotAuth&crlhashurl=login.aspx%3fdirect%3dtrue%26profile%3dehost%26scope%3dsite%26authtype%3dcrawler%26jrnl%3d09462104%26AN%3d49115546), Micke, O.; Schönekaes, K.; Mücke, R.; Kisters, K.; Büntzel, J., Trace Elements & Electrolytes . 2010 2nd Quarter, Vol. 27 Issue 2, p73-79. 7p.

> Pleasant feelings or seeming successes of crystal healing can be attributed to the strong placebo effect, or the believers wanting it to be true and seeing only things that back that up: cognitive bias. **A scientific proof of any positive effect beyond a placebo effect does not exist.** Even though this treatment can be generally regarded as harmless and without toxicity, it should not be recommended to cancer patients. Thereby we will help prevent our patients from wasting hope, time and money in an ineffective treatment, and at worst to postpone the necessary treatment of this life threatening disease, resulting in a worsened prognosis.

So, in the field of cancer treatment in particular, there is no evidence that crystals can heal.

The [Skeptics Dictionary](http://www.skepdic.com/crystals.html) (non-peer-reviewed web-site) makes a broader conclusion:

> There is no scientific evidence that crystals are conduits of magical energies useful for healing and protection, or for telling the future.

Comment: All well-stated.   That said, the placebo effect can be massive.  Interesting article: http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2011/12/12/the-power-of-nothing

Comment: @Minnow: This isn't the place to discuss the risks and ethics of deliberate placebo, and the confusion between the *actual* effects of a placebo treatment versus the effects found in the control group of an experiment. Suffice to say, that some people get better, unrelated to the application of crystal healing, does not make it an appropriate treatment.